# RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError in simple example

Tags: ruby, rspec, cucumber

I try to do some simple script 
`steps.rb` file

```
Given(/^I am on the YouTube home page$/) do
  visit 'http://www.youtube.com'
end
When(/^I search for "(.*?)"$/) do
|search_term|
  fill_in 'search_query', :with => search_term
  click_on 'search-btn'
end
Then(/^videos of large rodents are returned$/) do
  expect(page).to have_content 'Largest rodents'
end
```

and youtube.feature:

```
Feature: Search for Videos on YouTube
  Scenario: Search for Videos of Large Rodents
    Given I am on the YouTube home page
    When I search for "capybara"
    Then videos of large rodents are returned
 of course gemfile and env.rb


after run i got:
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected to find text "Largest rodents" in "Remind me later Review A privacy reminder from YouTube, a Google company PL (...)
./features/step_definitions/steps.rb:10:in `/^videos of large rodents are returned$/'
./features/youtube_search.feature:5:in `Then videos of large rodents are returned'
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: As the expectation failure suggests, Youtube is not returning the expected video anymore. Use something like [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) to "record" the queries.

Comment: thx. i teied to change on another text as result from https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=capybara e.g changed text expect(page).to have_content 'Largest rodents'
text Large rodents on for example: "Capybara Island!" but it does not work

Comment: Your `capybara` query does not end up with results that have `Largest rodents` text in it. If I am not mistaken, Youtube search results are different per user. Print the result set from your tests and analyse it. There should be no text with expected text.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a `sleep` in your code right before you do the expect. So that you can manually go through the page and confirm that the text is present.

If it's present, then it could be that the default wait time is too low and maybe the text takes some time to be visible in the page. If so, I would suggest doing:

`expect(page).to have_content("Largest rodents", wait: 15)`

In that case, the expect will allow a max wait time of 15 seconds before firing an expectation not met message.